# How to skip files in multi-root vscode placed in directory above workspace folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a multi-root workspace and have a launch config for one of the roots. I have `skipFiles` enabled to ignore all `.ts` files but the build step looks to be placing files in the *root* of the project instead of either of the roots. Thus, how do I reference the workspace root directory so that I can skip those files? One of those files I can't skip is this (which doesn't exist on disk):
`myproject/src/types/observableobject.ts`
All of my actual files exist in:

```
myproject/
  myproject-frontend/
    src/
  myproject-backend/
    src/
```

```
# myproject.code-workspace
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "myproject-backend"
        },
        {
            "path": "myproject-frontend"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
        "prettier.packageManager": "yarn"
    }
}
```

```
# myproject/myproject-frontend/.vscode/launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "smartStep": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      },
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/**/node_modules/*",
        "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.ts"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by just doing a glob pattern that is relevant to the disk root instead of the `workspaceFolder`:

```
“/**/*.ts”
```